# Unable to Delete the rows after deleting the data in a Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, gspread

```
 **Index   date            colum1       column2**
      0       20200705        a              1.1%
      1       20200706        b              78%
      2       20200707        f              10%
      3       20200707        g              59%
      4       20200708        a              69%
```

Consider the name of the above data frame as '`df`'.
I want to delete the data for the particular date
I tired the options below

```
dates =['20200707']
df= df[~df['date'].isin(dates)] (1st try)

 df.drop(df[df['date'].isin(dates)].index, inplace = True) (2nd try)
```

The data in those corresponding rows gets deleted but I'm ending up with the data frame as below

```
Index   date            column1       column2
0       20200705        a              1.1%
1       20200706        b              78%
2                                      0.0%
3                                      0.0%
4       20200708        a              69%
```

I  don't know why that happens and I didn't find any source to fix this kind of issue. So I have deleted `Column2` and performed the same operation and I ended up with the data frame as below

```
   Index   date            column1     
    0       20200705           a              
    1       20200706           b              
    2                                      
    3                                      
    4       20200708           a
```

Note: I'm importing the data from Google sheet by using `.get_all_records()` method and  converting that to a data frame

```
 df= sheet.worksheet('work_sheet').get_all_records()
    df= pd.DataFrame(df)
```

After the above operation,  I tried sorting the data, expecting that empty rows gets deleted

```
 df.sort_values(by='date')
```

but ended up with

```
 **Index   date            colum1       **
       2             
       3                                    
       0       20200705        a              
       1       20200706        b              
       4       20200708        a
```

I even tried by using dropna
**`df.dropna(inplace=True)`**
But there is no change in the result
I want that empty rows to be removed please help me
I tried everything, I tried to explain below please let me know incase of any questions

The strangest part is the empty lines where the data gets deleted after `df= df[~df['date'].isin(dates)]` operation are stored as `str` type and `' '` empty space as cell,

I wonder creating a dataframe out of data imported from Google sheet is causing me problems

Comment: Please enclose the code/output sections with "```" or using the button "{}" in the code editor

Comment: As mentioned by @qmeeus please follow SO rules

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure that the "date" column is a string and not a number?

Comment: This is my first question in the Forum, I'll try to edit as per the rules here , I know it might sound stupid but yea the problem is real and yes the date is a string(i have explicitly converted to a string)

Comment: May be you have to convert it to date explicitly ( for filtering) , filter it out and store the results.

Comment: the list I'm passing is in string format dates=[ '20200707' ]/ I have directly matched with the date type, the problem is data gets deleted but the the index for the same is not getting removed

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df = df[df['date'] !='20200707']
```